OSB vs Plywood for second layer of subfloor
I am renovating the kitchen in an old (1915) house that has maple flooring under the 6 layers of luan and vinyl.The 2" wide maple boards are not very even and we want to put down vinyl planking. We are considering 1/2" subflooring. I can get 5 layer plywood or 1/2 OSB for the job. Any recommendations?

"Not very even" means not flat?  Or not evenly spaced?

What do the instructions for your flooring specify? Are they OK with OSB, or do they insist on plywood?

Usually the only reason to prefer OSB over Plywood is that it costs less.
It's not as flat and it's more prone to water damage (this being a kitchen.)
If you can afford plywood, that's the better choice.

I have to dispute the "not as flat" statement. In my experience OSB is much more flat and stable than plywood, at least until it gets wet for a period of time. I've seen crazy warpage in BC plywood subfloor. Vinyl planks mostly eliminate the concern anyway.
